# How to integrate HTML5 & JavaScript in iPhone application?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, uiwebview, augmented-reality

I am working on one application in which I need to use one third party code which consists of HTML5 and Javascript and having html pages inside that product. Now I have opened that html pages in safari browser in my Mac machine as well as in my iPhone & iPad device and working fine. But now I need to implement that thing in webview using standard iOS application.

Here the application I am working on is regarding augmented reality. Is there any way to integrate this product in the iOS standard application specially in the webview without opening safari browser.

You can find the third party product [Here](http://krpano.com/download/). Let me know if anyone can help me here.

Answer (score 0):

dont afraid thinking of html 5. it is also very easy. you can use it in webview directly. if you need button event or any event method correctly tel me, i will provide sample code

Comment: I need to integrate complete package located at the following link: http://krpano.com/download/download.php?file=krpanotools10812mac

Comment: have you loaded in uiwebview.